# Bezier curves draw stretched ellipses in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, bezier, ellipse

This method for drawing ellipses appears to be clean and elegant: http://www.williammalone.com/briefs/how-to-draw-ellipse-html5-canvas/

However, in testing it, I found that the resulting ellipses were stretched. Setting width and height equal, I got ellipses that were about 20% taller than wide. Here's the result with `width = height = 50`:

[image: Tall canvas ellipse (should be circle)]

To make sure that the problem was with the method itself, I tried changing the algorithm so that all the points used for the Bezier curves were rotated 90 degrees. The result:

[image: Wide canvas ellipse(should be circle]

Again, in both cases, I was expecting a 50x50 circle. Using the `arc` method described at [How to draw an oval in html5 canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172798/how-to-draw-an-oval-in-html5-canvas) works fine, generating perfect 50x50 circles (which can then be stretched into ellipses using `scale`).

What's going on?

Answer (score 4):

In writing my question, I realized that I misunderstood the way Bézier curve control points work. Looking more closely at the [resource](http://www.williammalone.com/briefs/how-to-draw-ellipse-html5-canvas/) I was using, the ellipse's arcs never touch the `x - width / 2` and `x + width / 2` boundaries in the figure. So it's not really "width" at all.

In the future, I'll stick with `arc` instead of `bezierCurveTo`.

(It's possible to adjust for this using a "kappa"; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172798/how-to-draw-an-oval-in-html5-canvas/2173084#2173084). That approach is preferable to arc if you're using a `stroke`, not just a `fill`, since `scale` will cause uneven line thickness.)

Comment: Not to mention that an arc takes a fraction of the CPU time building a Bezier curve does.

Comment: That makes intuitive sense, but could you cite a source?

Comment: I do not advice to use **arc** function if you will do transformations to the ellipse. You need to stick with 4 or 8 cubic curve....as they will be able to handle the transformation properly