# Mapping SVG ARCTO to HTML Canvas ARCTO

Tags: canvas, svg, html5-canvas

ARCTO in [SVG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands) is quite different from the one we have in [Canvas](http://www.dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/canvas/CanvasArcTo.html). I have a use case where I will have the data as per SVG spec but I need to draw that on Canvas.

I tried this but I guess my geometry is weak. Can you please help?

Answer (score 5):

## Drawing only (Update)

As stated by [@V.Rubinetti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2180570/v-rubinetti), canvas' [`Path2D` can handle SVG path strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/Path2D#using_svg_paths). So if you are only concerned about drawing with javascript, you can use the arc from there, e.g.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let p = new Path2D("M10 10 h 80 v 80 h -80 Z");
ctx.fill(p);
```

If you, like me, need the actual arc to be transformed or, also like me, are actually not using javascript, use my initial answer in the following.

## Language agnostic (Initial answer)

*For an interactive example check out the code snippet below.*

I had the same problem so I came across this post. The [Implementation Requirements Appendix of the W3C SVG definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/implnote.html#ArcImplementationNotes) tells exactly how to convert form (they call it) end point parameterization to the center parameterization and back:

The SVG arc (end point parameterization) is described by:

- x<sub>1</sub>/y<sub>1</sub>: The start position (the position of the last path command)
- x<sub>2</sub>/y<sub>2</sub>: The end position of the arc (the `x` and `y` values of this path command)
- r<sub>x</sub>/r<sub>y</sub>: The x and y radius
- φ: The rotation angle
- f<sub>A</sub>: The large arc flag (1 or 0, whether to use the larg or the small arc)
- f<sub>S</sub>: The sweep flag (whether to go clockwise or anticlockwise)

The canvas arc uses (center point parameterization):

- c<sub>x</sub>/c<sub>y</sub>: The center point of the ellipse
- r<sub>x</sub>/r<sub>y</sub>: The x and y radius
- φ: The rotation angle
- θ<sub>1</sub>: The start angle of the ellipse (before rotation)
- Δθ: The angle distance to use of the ellipse (direction depends on the sweep flag f<sub>S</sub>, you can also calculate the end point θ<sub>2</sub> which may be even better)

### Convert from SVG to Canvas

This means converting from SVG to canvas you can use the following equations (taken directly from the given url from W3C):

> 1. Compute `(x1′, y1′)` (Equation F.6.5.1)
>
>    [image: Equation F.6.5.1]
> 2. Compute `(cx′, cy′)` (Equation F.6.5.2)
>
>    [image: Equation F.6.5.2]
>
>    where the + sign is chosen if f<sub>A</sub> ≠ f<sub>S</sub>, and the −
>    sign is chosen if f<sub>A</sub> = f<sub>S</sub>.
> 3. Compute `(cx, cy)` from `(cx′, cy′)` (Equation F.6.5.3)
>
>    [image: Equation F.6.5.3]
> 4. Compute θ<sub>1</sub> and Δθ (Equations F.6.5.5 and F.6.5.6)
>
>    **Edit: I am now using other equations, have a look at the bottom**
>
>    [image: Equation F.6.5.5]
>
>    [image: Equation F.6.5.6]
>
>    where θ<sub>1</sub> is fixed in the range −360° < Δθ < 360° such that:
>
>    if f<sub>S</sub> = 0, then Δθ < 0,
>
>    else if f<sub>S</sub> = 1, then Δθ > 0.
>
>    In other words, if f<sub>S</sub> = 0 and the right side of (F.6.5.6)
>    is greater than 0, then subtract 360°, whereas if f<sub>S</sub> = 1
>    and the right side of (F.6.5.6) is less than 0, then add 360°. In all
>    other cases leave it as is.

<sub>Copyright © 16 August 2011 World Wide Web Consortium, (MIT, ERCIM, Keio, Beihang). http://www.w3.org/Consortium/Legal/2015/doc-license</sub>

#### Edit: Modified equations for step 4.

I am now using the following equations for determining θ<sub>1</sub> and Δθ:

[image: Modified equation F.6.5.5]

[image: Modified Equation F.6.5.6]

This is simply the vectors between the start and end point of the arc and the center point. The φ is subtracted because of the angle is calculated before rotation. You may just leave this away if needed.

I received wrong results of the given equations but this may also be a bug in my implementation. When trying to find the bug I was thinking about what W3C is doing here. I was looking on how to calculate the angles and this was the first thing I thought about. This is leading to the correct results for me.

#### Example implementation

```js
function convertSVGToCanvas(x1, y1, x2, y2, rx, ry, phi, fa, fs) {
  if(rx <= 0 || ry <= 0) {
    throw new Exception("rx or ry is <= 0");
  }
  
  const p = phi / 180 * Math.PI;
  const x_m = (x1 - x2) / 2;
  const y_m = (y1 - y2) / 2;
  
  const x1_d = Math.cos(p) * x_m + Math.sin(p) * y_m;
  const y1_d = -Math.sin(p) * x_m + Math.cos(p) * y_m;
  
  const radius_check_value = (x1_d*x1_d)/(rx*rx) + (y1_d*y1_d)/(ry*ry);
  if(radius_check_value > 1) {
    // throw "Radius is too small to build an arc!";
    
    // Check out radius correction in the W3C document
    // https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/implnote.html#ArcCorrectionOutOfRangeRadii
    const r_sq = Math.sqrt(radius_check_value);
    rx = r_sq * rx;
    ry = r_sq * ry;
    
    console.error(`Radii are too small to build an arc. Correcting them to ${rx}/${ry}.`);
  }
  
  const sq = Math.sqrt(
    (rx*rx*ry*ry - rx*rx*y1_d*y1_d - ry*ry*x1_d*x1_d) / 
    (rx*rx*y1_d*y1_d + ry*ry*x1_d*x1_d)
  );
  
  const s = fa != fs ? 1 : -1;
  const cx_d = s * sq * rx*y1_d/ry;
  const cy_d = s * sq * -ry*x1_d/rx;
  
  const x_m_d = (x1 + x2) / 2;
  const y_m_d = (y1 + y2) / 2;
  const cx = Math.cos(p) * cx_d - Math.sin(p) * cy_d + x_m_d;
  const cy = Math.sin(p) * cx_d + Math.cos(p) * cy_d + y_m_d;
  
  const vectorAngle = (ux, uy, vx, vy) => (
    (ux*vy >= uy*vx ? 1 : -1) *
    Math.acos(
      (ux*vx + uy*vy) / 
      (Math.sqrt(ux*ux + uy*uy) * Math.sqrt(vx*vx + vy*vy))
    )
  );
  const theta_1 = vectorAngle(1, 0, x1 - cx, y1 - cy) - p;
  const delta_theta = vectorAngle(x1 - cx, y1 - cy, x2 - cx, y2 - cy);
  
  return [cx, cy, rx, ry, p, theta_1, theta_1 + delta_theta];
}

// for example only

function getInputs() {
  const inputs = ["x1", "y1", "x2", "y2", "rx", "ry", "phi", "fa", "fs"];
  return inputs.map((id) => (
    id == "fa" || id == "fs" 
    ? $(`#${id}`).prop("checked")
    : parseFloat($(`#${id}`).val())
  ));
}

function updateDrawing() {
  const [x1, y1, x2, y2, rx, ry, phi, fa, fs] = getInputs();
  
  // draw svg
  $("#path").attr("d", `M ${x1} ${y1} A ${rx} ${ry} ${phi} ${fa ? 1 : 0} ${fs ? 1 : 0} ${x2} ${y2}`);
  
  // draw canvas
  const canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.ellipse(0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.ellipse(canvas.width, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.ellipse(0, canvas.height, 5, 5, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.ellipse(canvas.width, canvas.height, 5, 5, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "transparent";
  const [cx, cy, canv_rx, canv_ry, canv_phi, theta_1, delta_theta] = convertSVGToCanvas(x1, y1, x2, y2, rx, ry, phi, fa, fs);
  
  ctx.ellipse(cx, cy, canv_rx, canv_ry, canv_phi, theta_1, delta_theta, !fs);
  ctx.stroke();

};

$(document).ready(() => {
  $("input").on("change", updateDrawing);
  updateDrawing();
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 150px auto;
  align-items: start;
}

svg, canvas {
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
}

.controls {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
}

.controls label[for="phi"]{
  grid-column: 2 / 5;
}

h1 {
  margin: 3px;
  font-size: 120%;
}

input {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>SVG</h1>
  <h1>Canvas</h1>
  <h1>Controls</h1>
  <svg id="svg" width="150" height="150">
    <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="5" fill="red" />
    <circle cx="150" cy="0" r="5" fill="red" />
    <circle cx="0" cy="150" r="5" fill="red" />
    <circle cx="150" cy="150" r="5" fill="red" />
    <path id="path" d="" stroke="green" fill="none" stroke-width="2" />
  </svg>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="x1" type="number" value="40" />
    <label for="x1">x1</label>
    <input id="y1" type="number" value="60" />
    <label for="y1">y1</label>
    
    <input id="x2" type="number" value="40" />
    <label for="x2">x2</label>
    <input id="y2" type="number" value="140" />
    <label for="y2">y2</label>
    
    <input id="rx" type="number" value="40" />
    <label for="rx">rx</label>
    <input id="ry" type="number" value="100" />
    <label for="ry">ry</label>
    
    <input id="phi" type="number" value="30" />
    <label for="phi">φ (in deg)</label>
    
    <input id="fa" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="fa">f<sub>A</sub></label>
    <input id="fs" type="checkbox" checked />
    <label for="fs">f<sub>S</sub></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Convert from Canvas to SVG

I also ran into problems when using the W3C equations when converting back. This may be because of changing the angles. For getting from Canvas to SVG you need to convert the start and end angles (θ<sub>1</sub> and θ<sub>2</sub> = θ<sub>1</sub> + Δθ) together with the center point to the intersections of the arc. Those are the start and end points of the SVG arc.

1. Compute `(x1', y1')` and `(x2', y2')`

   [image: Compute x1', y1', x2' and y2']

   This is calculating the intersection for the line which is defined by the given angle θ<sub>1</sub>/θ<sub>2</sub> in the rotated coordinate system. For the x coordinate the + sign should be chosen, when the -π/2 ≤ θ ≤ π/2. The + sign for the y coordinate should be chosen when 0 ≤ θ ≤ π.
2. Compute `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`

   [image: compute x1, y1, x2 and y2]

   The x and y coordinate of the start and end points can then be calculated by rotating back the rotation angle φ and translating the vector to the center of the ellipse.
3. Find the flags

   The flags can easily be determined: f<sub>A</sub> is 1 if Δθ is greater than 180°, fS is 1 if Δθ is greater than 0°.

Comment: If you just want to write arcs on canvas like you do in SVG, you could use the `<canvas>` [`Path2d` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/Path2D). I'd imagine its performance is worse than just doing the math yourself manually since it has to parse the path string.

Comment: @V.Rubinetti good hint, thank you. I've added it to the answer

Answer (score 3):

The difference between svg ellipse and canvas arc is that you have 2 radiuses in svg and only one in arcTo. Then you also need to rotate your arc on specific angle in canvas. To emulate 2 radiuses you need to make an arc with the given coordinates having the smallest radius. Then you need to scale this arc in a specific direction with coefficient(rx/ry). And now you need only to rotate. But in this approach is really hard to figurate out which part of the ellipse you want to show because it depends on the large-arc-flag and sweep-flag in svg spec. Another problem is to limit your arc by end coordinates(from svg spec). So by arcTo you can build a maximum of half of an ellipse, I guess.

You also may use a bezierCurveTo(x0,y0,x1,y1,x2,y2) to draw a part of an ellipse, if you have coordinates of 3 control points on your ellipse. With this approach you can build any segment of an ellipse. Of course, for segments more than PI you will need at least two curves

From the SVG spec you have (rx ry x-axis-rotation large-arc-flag sweep-flag x y). So the sample path would be like that:

```
  M100,100 a25,50 -30 0,1 50,-25
```

[Here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-bezier-curves/) you may find how bezier curves should be drawn.

Now you have a **context point** (which is 100,100), and an **end point** (which is 100+50,100-25) 
You need to calculate control points before rotation to -30 degrees.

Here the an example that works for me:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var startX = 100;
        var startY = 100;
        var dX = 50;
        var dY = -25;
        var angle = -30;
        var rx = 25;
        var ry = 50;
        var svg = Raphael($('#svg')[0], 200, 200);

        var path = "M" +startX + "," + startY + " a" + rx + "," + ry + " " + angle + " 0,1" + " " + dX + "," +dY;
        svg.path(path).attr({"stroke-width" : 2, "stroke" : "#FFFFFF"});

        var kappa = .5522848,
        ox = rx*kappa,
        oy = ry*kappa,
        xm = startX + rx,       // x-middle
        ym = startY + ry;       // y-middle
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.moveTo(startX,startY);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(startX, startY - oy, startX + ox, startY - ry, startX + rx, startY - ry);
        ctx.bezierCurveTo(startX + rx + ox, startY - ry, startX + 2*rx, startY - oy, startX + dX, startY + dY);
        ctx.stroke();
    });
```

markup is simply:

```
<div id="svg" style="border: 1px solid black;position : absolute;top : 50px;left : 50px;"></div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="200px" height="200px" style="border: 1px solid black;position : absolute;top : 300px;left : 50px;"></canvas>
```

the curves are not similar because I didnt rotate the control points to -30 degrees. But I believe that it is the only thing that you need to do. Because if you will put angle = 0. They will be similar
You may use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29) article to get the mathematics for rotation.

PS: I took some parts of code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172798/how-to-draw-an-oval-in-html5-canvas/2173084#2173084) answer

Comment: I couldn't find any reference to my case.

Comment: Thanks. Approach two is better. Approach one needs scaling, this will have one undesirable side-effect. This will cause the scaled out stoke part to expand, making the curve unevenly thick.

Comment: Well I have the value of only x0,y0, not of x1,y1 or x2,y2. Hmm... Not sure how to map them still.

Comment: Edited the answer little bit more :)

Comment: Are you happy with this answer?

Comment: Thanks for taking all the trouble. I will check this when I get back home.

Comment: I guess I am missing something. Pls check http://jsfiddle.net/qrgDD/1/ . Even if I set the angle to 0 then the curves are not same. Canvas one looks scaled down. And isn't rotating it would make the end points too rotate to a new location? Sorry but I still don't get it. Thanks for all the help till now. :)

Comment: See my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Fedor/qrgDD/29/. The curves should not be **exactly** the same because they were drawn by different algirithms insight different libraries. So I guess this it is kind of normal allowance.

Comment: So do you have any other questions? see the comment above

Comment: Thanks @Fedor. Will check it. Actually, I too am not looking for exact but similar curves. Will check it and get back to you.

Comment: this is very very nice, but one caveat. It doesn't consider the fact that angle also determines, how much of the ellipse is actually drawn. So trying setting the angle to some high value like -90 and you will notice the difference.

Comment: I have an idea. If somehow I can calculate the coordinate of ellipse's center then using I get the value of `t` in ellipse's General Parametric form, for both the end points. So, this will give me give me the range of `t` within which I should find the ctrl points. This can now be done by finding the coords at t=T/4 and 3T/4, where T=tStart-tEnd. Now these are the pts of midpt that can be used to find the ctrl pts. In case we know that this `t` range has only one bulge then we simply get a single ctrl pt at T/2 and draw a qudraticCurve using that.PS: Unsure if this will work, but looks okay.:)

Answer (score 2):

The following code segment was extracted from the relevant section of Gabe Lerner's comprehensive CANVG package (see https://github.com/canvg/canvg) for any of you out there, who like me, might not want the whole nine yards of Gabe's package. Unlike the earlier solutions it is not an approximation, it is the exact equivalent of the SVG arc path element for which I would like to thank Gabe enormously.

One further point is that if you have already applied some scaling and/or translation to the canvas prior to the plotting of the path, you will need to factor this into the parameters of the two calls to Context.translate and also into the radius parameter of the call to Context.arc

```
function drawSVGarcOnCanvas (Context,lastX,lastY,rx,ry,xAxisRotation,largeArcFlag,sweepFlag,x,y)
{
    //--------------------
    // rx, ry, xAxisRotation, largeArcFlag, sweepFlag, x, y
    // are the 6 data items in the SVG path declaration following the A
    //
    // lastX and lastY are the previous point on the path before the arc
    //--------------------
    // useful functions
    var m   = function (   v) {return Math.sqrt (Math.pow (v[0],2) + Math.pow (v[1],2))};
    var r   = function (u, v) {return ( u[0]*v[0] + u[1]*v[1]) / (m(u) * m(v))};
    var ang = function (u, v) {return ((u[0]*v[1] < u[1]*v[0])? -1 : 1) * Math.acos (r (u,v))};
    //--------------------

var currpX =  Math.cos (xAxisRotation) * (lastX - x) / 2.0 + Math.sin (xAxisRotation) * (lastY - y) / 2.0 ;
var currpY = -Math.sin (xAxisRotation) * (lastX - x) / 2.0 + Math.cos (xAxisRotation) * (lastY - y) / 2.0 ;

var l = Math.pow (currpX,2) / Math.pow (rx,2) + Math.pow (currpY,2) / Math.pow (ry,2);
if (l > 1) {rx *= Math.sqrt (l); ry *= Math.sqrt (l)};
var s = ((largeArcFlag == sweepFlag)? -1 : 1) * Math.sqrt 
      (( (Math.pow (rx,2) * Math.pow (ry    ,2)) - (Math.pow (rx,2) * Math.pow (currpY,2)) - (Math.pow (ry,2) * Math.pow (currpX,2))) 
       / (Math.pow (rx,2) * Math.pow (currpY,2) +   Math.pow (ry,2) * Math.pow (currpX,2)));
if (isNaN (s)) s = 0 ;

var cppX = s *  rx * currpY / ry ;
var cppY = s * -ry * currpX / rx ;
var centpX = (lastX + x) / 2.0 + Math.cos (xAxisRotation) * cppX - Math.sin (xAxisRotation) * cppY ;
var centpY = (lastY + y) / 2.0 + Math.sin (xAxisRotation) * cppX + Math.cos (xAxisRotation) * cppY ;

var ang1 = ang ([1,0], [(currpX-cppX)/rx,(currpY-cppY)/ry]);
var a = [(  currpX-cppX)/rx,(currpY-cppY)/ry];
var b = [(-currpX-cppX)/rx,(-currpY-cppY)/ry];
var angd = ang (a,b);
if (r (a,b) <= -1) angd = Math.PI;
if (r (a,b) >=  1) angd = 0;

var rad = (rx > ry)? rx : ry;
var sx  = (rx > ry)? 1 : rx / ry;
var sy  = (rx > ry)? ry / rx : 1;

Context.translate (centpX,centpY);
Context.rotate (xAxisRotation);
Context.scale (sx, sy);
Context.arc (0, 0, rad, ang1, ang1 + angd, 1 - sweepFlag);
Context.scale (1/sx, 1/sy);
Context.rotate (-xAxisRotation);
Context.translate (-centpX, -centpY);
};
```

Comment: Do you have permission to post Gabe's code? I.e. does the licence permit this?

Answer (score 1):

When trying to map "M100,100 a25,50 -30 0,1 50,-25" to  canvas use my function.
Granted I wrote this with circlular arcs in mind.

ellipse(100,100,50,-25,50,false);

```
function ellipse(x1, y1, x2, y2, radius, clockwise) {

var cBx = (x1 + x2) / 2;    //get point between xy1 and xy2
var cBy = (y1 + y2) / 2;
var aB = Math.atan2(y1 - y2, x1 - x2);  //get angle to bulge point in radians
if (clockwise) { aB += (90 * (Math.PI / 180)); }
else { aB -= (90 * (Math.PI / 180)); }
var op_side = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2)) / 2;
var adj_side = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(radius, 2) - Math.pow(op_side, 2));

if (isNaN(adj_side)) {
    adj_side = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(op_side, 2) - Math.pow(radius, 2));
}

var Cx = cBx + (adj_side * Math.cos(aB));            
var Cy = cBy + (adj_side * Math.sin(aB));
var startA = Math.atan2(y1 - Cy, x1 - Cx);       //get start/end angles in radians
var endA = Math.atan2(y2 - Cy, x2 - Cx);
var mid = (startA + endA) / 2;
var Mx = Cx + (radius * Math.cos(mid));
var My = Cy + (radius * Math.sin(mid));
context.arc(Cx, Cy, radius, startA, endA, clockwise);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little late, but here is a solution that will allow to draw wedges, like pie charts.  The solution uses all of the input from this thread.  So I thought I would share.  Note that it does not implement the checks for radii....

Dependencies are [mathjs](https://mathjs.org) and [d3Shape](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape)

```
function toContext(x1, y1, path) {
  let fvals = path.split(',').map(item => parseFloat(item)); 
  const rx = fvals[0];
  const ry = fvals[1];
  const phi = toRad(fvals[2]);
  const fA = fvals[3];
  const fS = fvals[4];
  const x2 = fvals[5];
  const y2 = fvals[6];

  const cosPhi = Math.cos(phi);
  const sinPhi = Math.sin(phi);
  const dx = (x1 - x2) / 2.0;
  const dy = (y1 - y2) / 2.0;

  let A = math.matrix([[cosPhi, sinPhi], [-sinPhi, cosPhi]]);
  let B = math.matrix([[dx], [dy]]);
  let C = math.multiply(A,B);
  const x1_ = C.valueOf()[0][0];
  const y1_ = C.valueOf()[1][0];
  console.log(`x1_ ${x1_}, y1_ ${y1_} : ${C.valueOf()}`);

  // step2
  const rx2 = rx*rx;
  const ry2 = ry*ry;
  const x1_2 = x1_*x1_;
  const y1_2 = y1_*y1_;

  const g0 = rx2*ry2 - rx2*y1_2 - ry2*x1_2;
  const g1 = rx2*y1_2 + ry2*x1_2;
  let sq = Math.sqrt(g0/g1);
  let sign = (fA === fS) ? -1.0 : 1.0;
  sq = sq * sign;
  const cx_ = sq * ((rx*y1_)/ry);
  const cy_ = sq * -((ry*x1_)/rx);

  A = math.matrix([[cosPhi, -sinPhi], [sinPhi, cosPhi]]);
  B = math.matrix([[cx_], [cy_]]);
  C = math.multiply(A,B);
  let cx = C.valueOf()[0][0];
  let cy = C.valueOf()[1][0];
  cx += ((x1 + x2) / 2.0);
  cy += ((y1 + y2) / 2.0);
  console.log(`cx: ${cx}, cy: ${cy}`);

  const ux = (x1_ - cx_) / rx;
  const uy = (y1_ - cy_) / ry;
  const vx = (-x1_ - cx_) / rx;
  const vy = (-y1_ - cy_) / ry;
  let n = Math.sqrt((ux*ux) + (uy*uy));
  let p = ux;

  sign = (uy < 0) ? -1.0 : 1.0;
  let sa = 180.0 *(sign * Math.acos(p/n)) / Math.PI;

  n = Math.sqrt((ux*ux + uy*uy) * (vx*vx + vy*vy));
  p = ux*vx + uy*vy;
  sign = (ux*vy - uy*vx < 0) ? -1.0 : 1.0;
  let ea = 180.0 *(sign * Math.acos(p/n)) / Math.PI;
  if( !fS && ea > 0 ){
    ea -= 360.0;
  } else if( fS && ea < 0) {
    ea += 360.0;
  }

  sa %= 360.0;
  ea %= 360.0;

  sa = toRad(sa);
  ea = toRad(ea);
  const clockWise = 1 - fS;

  return {x1, y1, x2, y2, cx, cy, sa, ea, phi, rx, ry, clockWise}
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/vetrostudios/pen/KKwNrrm?editors=0011)

Answer (score 0):

It took a bit of testing to get the two flags and rotation right, but this seems good:

```
function get_ellipse_args(
  px, py,     // last position, set implictly by most commands.
  
  // the remaining args are as for SVG's 'A' element.
  rx, ry, angle,
  largeArc, sweepPositive,
  x, y,
  
  // for SVG, if the radii are too small, scale up uniformly until just big enough.
  // If this is false, just throw an exception on bad data.
  scaleIfNeeded=true
) {
  const rotation = angle * Math.PI / 180;
  const cosr = Math.cos(rotation);
  const sinr = Math.sin(rotation);

  // Un-rotate the ellipse and then scale so that
  // our ellipse will be a unit-circle in the "u_" coordinate system.
  const u_px = (px * cosr + py * sinr) / rx;
  const u_py = (-px * sinr + py * cosr) / ry;
  const u_x = (x * cosr + y * sinr) / rx;
  const u_y = (-x * sinr + y * cosr) / ry;

  // Compute the distance between them.
  // In the unit-center coordinates write p1=upx,upy, p2=px,py, mid=average(p1,p2),
  // and 'center' as the center of a unit center that intersects both of them.
  //   p1
  //    |
  //.  mid            center
  //    |
  //   p2
  // p1,mid,c and p2,mid,c form symmetric right triangles with hypotenuse=1,
  // and 'mid' as the right - what we call the "leg" below is "mid-center"
  const u_dx = u_x - u_px;
  const u_dy = u_y - u_py;
  const dist_sq = u_dx * u_dx + u_dy * u_dy;
  
  // We allow.a tiny fudge factor if rounding might cause the points to be a hair to far apart.
  if (dist_sq > 4.000001) {
    if (scaleIfNeeded) {
      const scale = Math.sqrt(dist_sq / 4);
      return get_ellipse_args(px, py, rx * scale, ry * scale, angle,
        largeArc, sweepPositive,
        x, y
      );
    } else {
      throw Error('these arc params cannot be fulfilled- too far apart');
    }
  }
  
  const leg_sq = 1.0 - dist_sq / 4;
  // leg_sq should be non-negative, but due to rounding errors,
  // we treat near-zero as 0.
  const leg_scale = Math.sqrt((leg_sq <= 0.0 ? 0.0 : leg_sq) / dist_sq);
  const leg_x = -u_dy * leg_scale;
  const leg_y = u_dx * leg_scale;
  const u_cx = (u_x + u_px) / 2;
  const u_cy = (u_y + u_py) / 2;
  // possible centers are uc +/- leg.
  //    !large_arc,  sweepPos    center=uc+leg cw
  //    !large_arc, !sweepPos    center=uc-leg ccw
  //     large_arc,  sweepPos    center=uc+leg cw
  //     large_arc, !sweepPos    center=uc-leg ccw
  const leg_sign = (sweepPositive ? -1 : 1) * (largeArc ? 1 : -1);

  // center of the unit-center that we have chosen.
  const u_ecx = u_cx + leg_x * leg_sign;
  const u_ecy = u_cy + leg_y * leg_sign;

  // the angles are computed on the unscaled ellipse.
  const start_angle = Math.atan2(u_py - u_ecy, u_px - u_ecx);
  const end_angle = Math.atan2(u_y - u_ecy, u_x - u_ecx);

  // unrotated ellipse center.
  const su_ecx = u_ecx * rx;
  const su_ecy = u_ecy * ry;

  // rotated ellipse center.
  const cx = (su_ecx * cosr - su_ecy * sinr);
  const cy = (su_ecx * sinr + su_ecy * cosr);
  return [cx, cy, rx, ry, rotation, start_angle, end_angle, !sweepPositive];
}
```

Snippet:

```js
function get_ellipse_args(
  px, py,     // last position, set implictly by most commands.
  
  // the remaining args are as for SVG's 'A' element.
  rx, ry, angle,
  largeArc, sweepPositive,
  x, y,
  
  // for SVG, if the radii are too small, scale up uniformly until just big enough.
  // If this is false, just throw an exception on bad data.
  scaleIfNeeded=true
) {
  const rotation = angle * Math.PI / 180;
  const cosr = Math.cos(rotation);
  const sinr = Math.sin(rotation);

  // Un-rotate the ellipse and then scale so that
  // our ellipse will be a unit-circle in the "u_" coordinate system.
  const u_px = (px * cosr + py * sinr) / rx;
  const u_py = (-px * sinr + py * cosr) / ry;
  const u_x = (x * cosr + y * sinr) / rx;
  const u_y = (-x * sinr + y * cosr) / ry;

  // Compute the distance between them.
  // In the unit-center coordinates write p1=upx,upy, p2=px,py, mid=average(p1,p2),
  // and 'center' as the center of a unit center that intersects both of them.
  //   p1
  //    |
  //.  mid            center
  //    |
  //   p2
  // p1,mid,c and p2,mid,c form symmetric right triangles with hypotenuse=1,
  // and 'mid' as the right - what we call the "leg" below is "mid-center"
  const u_dx = u_x - u_px;
  const u_dy = u_y - u_py;
  const dist_sq = u_dx * u_dx + u_dy * u_dy;
  
  // We allow.a tiny fudge factor if rounding might cause the points to be a hair to far apart.
  if (dist_sq > 4.000001) {
    if (scaleIfNeeded) {
      const scale = Math.sqrt(4 / dist_sq);
      return get_ellipse_args(px, py, rx * scale, ry * scale, angle,
        largeArc, sweepPositive,
        x, y
      );
    } else {
      throw Error('these arc params cannot be fulfilled- too far apart');
    }
  }
  
  const leg_sq = 1.0 - dist_sq / 4;
  // leg_sq should be non-negative, but due to rounding errors,
  // we treat near-zero as 0.
  const leg_scale = Math.sqrt((leg_sq <= 0.0 ? 0.0 : leg_sq) / dist_sq);
  const leg_x = -u_dy * leg_scale;
  const leg_y = u_dx * leg_scale;
  const u_cx = (u_x + u_px) / 2;
  const u_cy = (u_y + u_py) / 2;
  // possible centers are uc +/- leg.
  //    !large_arc,  sweepPos    center=uc+leg cw
  //    !large_arc, !sweepPos    center=uc-leg ccw
  //     large_arc,  sweepPos    center=uc+leg cw
  //     large_arc, !sweepPos    center=uc-leg ccw
  const leg_sign = (sweepPositive ? -1 : 1) * (largeArc ? 1 : -1);

  // center of the unit-center that we have chosen.
  const u_ecx = u_cx + leg_x * leg_sign;
  const u_ecy = u_cy + leg_y * leg_sign;

  // the angles are computed on the unscaled ellipse.
  const start_angle = Math.atan2(u_py - u_ecy, u_px - u_ecx);
  const end_angle = Math.atan2(u_y - u_ecy, u_x - u_ecx);

  // unrotated ellipse center.
  const su_ecx = u_ecx * rx;
  const su_ecy = u_ecy * ry;

  // rotated ellipse center.
  const cx = (su_ecx * cosr - su_ecy * sinr);
  const cy = (su_ecx * sinr + su_ecy * cosr);
  return [cx, cy, rx, ry, rotation, start_angle, end_angle, !sweepPositive];
}



function start() {
  let canvas = document.getElementById('main-canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  let canvas_width = canvas.width;
  let canvas_height = canvas.height;
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas_width, canvas_height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
    ctx.moveTo(i*100,0);
    ctx.lineTo(i*100,400);
    ctx.moveTo(0,i*100);
    ctx.lineTo(400,i*100);
  }
  ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
  ctx.stroke();
  console.log(document.getElementById('moveto').value)
  
  const initial = document.getElementById('moveto').value.trim().split(/[\s,]+/mg).map(parseFloat);
  const arcto_params = document.getElementById('arcto').value.trim().split(/[\s,]+/mg).map(parseFloat);
  if (initial.length != 2) {
    alert(`expected 2 numbers for initial, got ${initial.length}`);
    return;
  }

  
  //ctx.fillStyle = '#f0f0f0';
  //ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas_width, canvas_height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  const all_args = initial.concat(arcto_params);
  const ellipse_args = get_ellipse_args(...all_args)
  ctx.ellipse(...ellipse_args);
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#f00';
  ctx.stroke();

  const p = document.getElementById('demo-path');
  const d = `M${initial.map(x => x.toString()).join(' ')}\n` +
            `A${arcto_params.map(x => x.toString()).join(' ')}`;
  document.getElementById('svg-d').textContent =    d;
  const to_s = f => f.toFixed(3);
  const rad_to_s = to_s;
  const comment_pairs = [
    [`${to_s(ellipse_args[0])}, ${to_s(ellipse_args[1])}`, 'ellipse center'],
    [`${to_s(ellipse_args[2])}, ${to_s(ellipse_args[3])},`,  'x,y radii'],
    [`${rad_to_s(ellipse_args[4])},`, 'rotation in radians'],
    [`${rad_to_s(ellipse_args[5])},${rad_to_s(ellipse_args[6])},`, 'start/end angles in radians'],
    [`${ellipse_args[7]}`, 'is CCW'],
  ];
  const commented_lines = comment_pairs.map(([txt,com]) => `  ${txt.padEnd(22, ' ')}// ${com}`).join("\n");
  document.getElementById(`canvas-js`).textContent = `ctx.ellipse(\n${commented_lines}\n)`;

  //console.log(`d=${d}`);
  //console.log(`ellipse ${JSON.stringify(get_ellipse_args(...all_args))}`);
  p.setAttribute('d', d);
}

start();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fcf;
}
svg, canvas {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
pre {
   background-color: #f0d8f0;
}
```

```html
<table><tr>
<td>canvas</td>
<td>svg</td>
</tr><tr>
<td><canvas id='main-canvas' width='400' height='400'>
</canvas></td>
<td>
<svg height="400" width="400">
  <path stroke='black' stroke-width="0.5" 
      d="M 0 0 400 0 M 0 100 400 100 M 0 200 400 200 M 0 300 400 300 M 0 400 400 400
         M 0 0 0 400 M 100 0 100 400 M 200 0 200 400 M 300 0 300 400 M 400 0 400 400" />
  <path fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" id="demo-path" d="M100 100" />
</svg> 
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    moveto: <input id='moveto' value='100 200'>
    <br>
    arcto: <input id='arcto' value='200 150 15 0 0 300 100'>
    <br>Reminder: arcto format is rx ry angle large-arc-flag sweep-positive-flag x y.
    <p>
    <button onclick='start()'>
    Update!
    </button>
    </p>
  </td>
 
  <td>SVG<br><pre id='svg-d'></pre>
  <br>Canvas<br><pre id='canvas-js'></pre></td>
</tr>
</table>
```