# Canvas arcTo in Raphael

Tags: javascript, canvas, raphael

I cannot seem to find HTML5 Canvas `arcTo` equivalent in the Raphael API.

Canvas sandbox can be found [here](http://jsbin.com/rixuqa/2/). Raphaels' [here](http://jsbin.com/hakiduwuxi/3/).

The relevant bits I assume are here:

```
var outA2 = Math.pow(cornerX - outX, 2);
var outB2 = Math.pow(cornerY - outY, 2);
var outC = Math.sqrt(outA2 + outB2);

var inA2 = Math.pow(cornerX - inX, 2);
var inB2 = Math.pow(cornerY - inY, 2);
var inC = Math.sqrt(inA2 + inB2);

var r = Math.min(outC, inC) / 2;

// ctx.lineTo(inX, inY);
path.push(['L', inX, inY]);

// ctx.arcTo(cornerX, cornerY, outX, outY, r);
path.push(['Q', cornerX, cornerY, outX, outY]);

// ctx.lineTo(outX, outY);
path.push(['L', outX, outY]);
```

Where, when making the *curve*, I have not passed radius or alike, but I just cannot seem to find such API.

How to recreate the `arcTo` result with Raphael?

Comment: Maybe this? http://zreference.com/raphael-2-0-catmull-rom-splines/

Comment: Also see open issue: https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/312

Comment: @Paul, nah, the Catmull algorithm didn't help - [see here](http://jsbin.com/sejori/2/).

Comment: This code has an arcTo extension defined. https://gist.github.com/radamant/362371

Comment: [SVG arcTo vs Canvas arcTo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729056/mapping-svg-arcto-to-html-canvas-arcto)