# Mapping Microsoft EllipticalArcTo to ECMA-376 arcTo

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

I have a use case where I have to convert parameters representing the arc of an ellipse. I have `x`, `y`, `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` from the Office add-in [EllipticalArcTo function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/ellipticalarcto-row-geometry-section) and I need to convert it to `hR`, `stAng`, `swAng`, `wR` as described in the [Office Open XML v1](https://c-rex.net/samples/ooxml/e1/Part4/OOXML_P4_DOCX_arcTo_topic_ID0EZZENB.html) spec (ECMA-376).

I tried to find similar questions solved, and I guess [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729056/mapping-svg-arcto-to-html-canvas-arcto) may be helpful.

It would be good to see convert realization in JS. But any help appreciated. I tried this but I guess my geometry is weak. Can you please help?

Comment: Comparing the linked documentation, it would seem ECMA-376 can only do axis-aligned ellipses, i.e. the case where parameter C from the Microsoft specification is zero.

Comment: You are right, lets consider C = 0

Comment: ECMA-376 is talking about “circle” while depicting (and in some places describing) an ellipse. Makes me wonder whether the things it describes as “angle” are actual angles, or might be [eccentric anomalies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentric_anomaly) instead. And whether implementations even agree on their interpretation of this. I wouldn't be surprised if this is a rarely used and buggy feature, and turning elliptic arcs into an approximation by cubic Bézier curves turns out to be way more portable.

Comment: it... doesn't? ECMA-376 describes an elliptical arc _\*as\*_ an elliptical arc, with the standard "absolute start angle and relative end angle" and radii described as "width" and "height" radii because it's there's no rotation, all ellipses are axis-aligned (with rotation coming from the "box" the ellipse is in, not the ellipse itself).

Comment: Also the "only" challenge is to convert the Office Add-on format--specifying the ellipse as going through three points--to the "conventional" format of start and end angles. Thankfully, loads of people already worked out the math for that both on the web (easy to find with "ellipse through three points") and other stackexchange sites like the [math.se] site. E.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204364

Comment: Ecma Office Open XML Part 1 PDF section 20.1.9.4 writes: “An arc is a line that is bent based on the shape of a supposed circle”. Also the `hR` attribute specifies “the height radius of the supposed circle”, likewise for `wR`. All of this is repeated literally on the [linked documentation page](https://c-rex.net/samples/ooxml/e1/Part4/OOXML_P4_DOCX_arcTo_topic_ID0EZZENB.html). So that's the mis-use of the term “circle” which causes me to doubt their wording altogether.