# How to draw an ellipse in encapsulated post script?

Tags: eps

EPS has the `arc` command

`xcenter ycenter radius startangle stopangle arc`

which will draw a circular arc at the desired around the desired location. How can I draw an ellipse?

Answer (score 0):

With curves :-)

You need to look at the curveto operator, then define your ellipse as a series of Bezier curves.

See also the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169234/the-relation-of-the-bezier-curve-and-ellipse)

Answer (score 0):

Try rather this postscript command:

```
/DrawEllipse {
    /endangle exch def
    /startangle exch def
    /yrad exch def
    /xrad exch def
    /y exch def
    /x exch def
    /savematrix mtrx currentmatrix def
    x y translate xrad yrad scale 0 0 1 startangle endangle arc
    savematrix setmatrix
    } def
```

The ellipse will never be precisely approximated by bezier curves. Stretching circle could also work.