# porting delphi canvas ellipse function to javascript arc function

Tags: javascript, delphi

Is it possible to port the [TCanvas.Ellipse](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.Ellipse) method from Delphi

```
Ellipse(X1,Y1,X2,Y2);
```

to [arc](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_arc.asp) method in JavaScript ?

```
arc(x,y,r,sAngle,eAngle,counterclockwise);
```

Thanks

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172798/how-to-draw-an-oval-in-html5-canvas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct, general translation; the Delphi function draws ellipses, while the JavaScript function only draws circular arcs, which are incapable of drawing ellipses (although it can be approximated).

If you were using `Ellipse` to draw a *circle*, then the conversion is simple. Calculate the center of the rectangle (square, really), and then calculate half the height or width for the radius. The documentation linked in the question already mentions the angles to use for a full circle, and clockwise or counterclockwise doesn't matter.

```
arc(x1+(x2-x1)/2, y1+(y2-y1)/2, (x2-x1)/2, 0, Math.PI/2);
```

If you want an ellipse, consider using [something other than `arc`, like Bezier curves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2173084/33732).