# Javascript - Calculate Kappa

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas

When drawing ellipses curves in HTML5, Canvas there's no inbuilt function, you have to scale, or make your own, I've seen this:

```
function drawEllipse(ctx, x, y, w, h) {
  var kappa = .5522848,
      ox = (w / 2) * kappa, // control point offset horizontal
      oy = (h / 2) * kappa, // control point offset vertical
      xe = x + w,           // x-end
      ye = y + h,           // y-end
      xm = x + w / 2,       // x-middle
      ym = y + h / 2;       // y-middle

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, ym);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(x, ym - oy, xm - ox, y, xm, y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(xm + ox, y, xe, ym - oy, xe, ym);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(xe, ym + oy, xm + ox, ye, xm, ye);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(xm - ox, ye, x, ym + oy, x, ym);
  //ctx.closePath(); // not used correctly, see comments (use to close off open path)
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

But where does that "kappa" come from? How do you calculate it, is it an infinite number (in decimals)?

Comment: Just a heads up in chrome you can use `ellipse` now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172798/how-to-draw-an-oval-in-html5-canvas/23184724#23184724

Comment: http://www.whizkidtech.redprince.net/bezier/circle/kappa/

Comment: Thanks. Make an answer and I'll accept it. You were first of all here.

Comment: @Murplyx :) I definitely appreciate that, but don't sweat it. Accept one of the other guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kappa is calculated this way:

[image: Kappa]

[Source](http://whizkidtech.redprince.net/bezier/circle/)

However, it will never produce a mathematical correct ellipse. For that you can use a method like this instead:

```
function drawEllipse(ctx, cx, cy, rx, ry) {

    var step = 0.01,                 // resolution of ellipse
        a = step,                    // counter
        pi2 = Math.PI * 2 - step;    // end angle

    /// set start point at angle 0
    ctx.moveTo(cx + rx, cy);
    for(; a < pi2; a += step) {
        ctx.lineTo(cx + rx * Math.cos(a), cy + ry * Math.sin(a));
    }
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

An `ellipse()` method is **[actually a part of the specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-ellipse)** and as Loktar points out in comments it is available in Chrome and will be in the other browsers later.

Answer (score 0):

In differential geometry, the [curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature) of a curve is given by κ (kappa).

Thus, the value of `kappa` determines the curves of your ellipse, and `.5522848` might just be a choice of the developer behind this piece of code.

According to this table ([from wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspheric_lens)), a positive curvature determines an ellipse :

[image]