# Java draw arc method equivalent in HTML5

Tags: java, html5-canvas

We were drawing arc in my java application using drawArc method provided by java api. That is

```
drawArc(int x, int y, int width, int height, int startAngle, int arcAngle)
```

I am searching for similar method in Html but i couldn't succed. There is only

`drawArc(x, y, radius, startangle, arcangle)` method  there.

Is there any equivalent method in Html as it in Java. If not then could you please guide me about any alternate method so that i can succeed.

Comment: Please take a look at [drawing oval in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172798/how-to-draw-an-oval-in-html5-canvas)

Answer (score 0):

There exists an experimental `ellipse` function in some browsers, but you can use a geometrical transformation (a vertical/horizontal scaling) to obtain the effect. If your original Java call was:

```
drawArc(x, y, width, height, startAngle, arcAngle)
```

It be realized with:

```
if (width>height) {
    gctx.setTransform(width/(float)height,0,0,1,0,0)
    radius = height
} else {
    gctx.setTransform (1,0,0,height/(float)width,0,0)       
    radius = width
}
gctx.drawArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, arcAngle)
```