# How to cut 1/n from a circle in css?

Tags: css

[image]

How to make such a shape in CSS?
In Figma it is called arc/sweep.
The maximum that I found was an implementation through polygon overlays, but I can’t implement it. It seems like a simple task, but two days of research led to nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55343364/2817442) answer, here it is:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #433f3f;
}

.pacman {
  width: 495px;
  height: 495px;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 50%, 50% 50%, 85.5% 0%);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="pacman"></div>
```